# How can I revert my edit, when it is still in the review queue?

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I made a stupid edit on another guy's question and can't revert it (yet). Maybe my stupidity will be catched by the peer reviewers, maybe not. In the first case, I stole a bit of the precious time of the peer reviewers, in the second case, it will be super annoying and embarrassing, as I would have to explain why my edit was wrong in the first place. But right now my hands are tied!

Is there no way to just delete one's edits from the peer review queue? 
Because there should be!

Comment: You can edit your edit, and at least put "Sorry, reject this" instead of the stupid edit it originally was. :)

Comment: So then there would be two edits in the queue? Is this the canonical way? It would be much more painless if I could just stop my own mistake. Also, wouldn't this count as two rejected edits on my part? That does not make for great statistics...

Comment: No, if you edit a post while you have a previous edit suggested on it (which was not approved or rejected yet), the new edit will overwrite the previous edit.

Comment: Do you mean [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/19390219)? It got approved, you want me to rollback?

Comment: Yes please ^^ I was too slow... Overwriting the edit seems quite reasonable, thank you for that suggestion! I'll keep that in mind if I commit another mistake like that in the future.